# Handling an empty 'else if'

Tags: c

I recently came across a situation in C I've never encountered before.

I have a C statement similar to the example below.  What is considered the best practice in such a situation? If I don't want to do anything for that input, but don't want to error, would empty {}'s suffice or is there a better standard?

```
for( traverse = input; *traverse != '\0'; traverse++ )
{
    if( *traverse == 'a' ) {
        // do things
    }
    else if( *traverse == 'b' ) {
        // do other things
    }
    else if( *traverse == 'c' ) {
        // don't do anything
        // continue loop, but don't error
    }
    else
        // error handling here
}
```

Comment: I usually use `else {;}` because that is the kind of thing you don't type by accident.

Comment: @wildplasser: and that would be okay with an else if{;}?

Comment: why not using a switch case?

Comment: No, but that would be exactly want to be the kind of case you want to catch ( -->> and let the compiler barf on you. Failfast, baby ...) BTW: I agree that in parsers/lexers continue is a life-saver (mainly because it avoids nesting)

Comment: @HAL9000: the if statements are pretty deep.  This is a pretty basic example.

Comment: I do it just like you're written, with the comment included so others know it's an intentional do-nothing case.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Thanks for the added input.  I'll go with keeping the continue keyword as well as the comment.

Comment: BTW: the tokenizer in my https://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/files/ (wakkerbot) project uses the continue-technique. It is the only way to avoid unreadable nesting, IMHO, (or recursive descent). Just do your thing and grab the next character and continue. BTW2: this is actually a very good question, because it is about style, robustness and readability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I'd write it as:

```
else if( *traverse == 'c' ) 
    continue;
```

This makes it fairly explicit that you want to continue with the next iteration of the loop without doing anything else in this iteration.

While an empty pair of braces would work just as well from the compiler's viewpoint, I think the `continue` makes the intent more apparent to anybody else reading the code (and helps ensure they won't think there were intended to be statements there that were accidentally deleted, or something on that order).

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  I couldn't figure out what the keyword to do nothing on that input was. I'll accept it when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `switch`:

```
for( traverse = input; *traverse != '\0'; traverse++ )
{
    switch( *traverse ) {
        case 'a':
            // do things
            break;
        case 'b':
            // do other things
            break;
        case 'c':
            // don't do anything
            break;
        default:
            //error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case a switch is less than desirable since the if statements contain a lot of code.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you want to put these code in individual functions, so the logic and structure of your code could be clearer.

Comment: It's fairly easy to follow, and the accepted answer works well. All in all, the entire function is about 60 lines. Not unmanageable really.

Comment: Well, it is only a suggestion, and may not be appropriate to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is how to handle an empty else. But the solution in this specific case would be to change this lines:

```
else if( *traverse == 'c' ) {
// don't do anything
// continue loop, but don't error
}
else
// error handling here
```

into:

```
else if( *traverse != 'c' ) {
// error handling here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a typical example of a XY-problem (see http://xyproblem.info/) where the question is about, basically, the wrong problem.

You should just write your code for the last bit as:

```
else if( *traverse != 'c' ) {
    // error handling here
}
```